# Glide. Cache to External Storage (SD card)

Tags: android, android-glide

I use [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) for loading Images in my android application.
After 3.5 update, developers provided [GlideModule](http://bumptech.github.io/glide/javadocs/360/index.html?com/bumptech/glide/module/GlideModule.html) interface.
According to [this article](https://github.com/bumptech/glide/wiki/Configuration#disk-cache) (Disk Cache) I can set cache directory, using `setDiskCache` method and `ExternalCacheDiskCacheFactory`.
But I doesn't see any difference. All cache still on the Internal storage in default cache directory.

---

**build.gradle**:

```
dependencies {
    ...
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.6.1'
}
```

**Android Manifest**:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<application ...>
<meta-data
        android:name="com.myapp.GlideConfig"
        android:value="GlideModule" />
</application>
```

**GlideConfig.java**:

```
public class GlideConfig implements GlideModule {
    @Override
    public void applyOptions(Context context, GlideBuilder builder) {
        String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
        if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state)) {
            Log.e("GlideConfig", "MEDIA_MOUNTED");
            builder.setDiskCache(
                context.getString(R.string.app_name),
                        419430400));//400Mb
            //Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()
            // + "/"
            // + context.getString(R.string.app_name)
        }
        else {
            Log.e("GlideConfig", "!MEDIA_MOUNTED");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void registerComponents(Context context, Glide glide) {
    }
}
```

**proguard-rules.pro**:

```
...
-keepnames class * com.myapp.GlideConfig
```

**Glide usage**:

```
Glide.with(context)
.load("some_url")
.dontAnimate()
.centerCrop()
.override(100, 100)
.into(holder.iv_image);
```

Comment: What do you consider to be the 'internal storage default cache directory'? The code looks OK to me, so I'm wondering if this is just a matter of confusion over what Android considers to be internal/external storage..

Comment: @TimMalseed, there are no confusion. Glide and other image loaders put image-cache to '/data/data/com.package/cache' (Internal storage) by default. But 'GlideModule' feature should do the trick. Maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: What device/ROM are you testing this on? You cannot say 'there is no confusion'. When it comes to internal/external storage on Android, even Google are confused.

Comment: @TimMalseed Samsung Galaxy S2.

Comment: If you put a log statement in applyOptions in your GlideModule is anything printed? Can you narrow down the problem to your Factory or the GlideModule

Comment: @SamJudd yes, see GlideConfig.java update. Log "GlideConfig"  "MEDIA_MOUNTED" on Application started.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To setup `GlideBuilder` with value of `setDiskCache`  You can set your ExternalStorageDirectory as a cache directory.

```
  if (!Glide.isSetup()) {
   GlideBuilder gb = new GlideBuilder(this);
   DiskCache dlw = DiskLruCacheWrapper.get(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/YourCacheDirectory/"), 250 * 1024 * 1024);
   gb.setDiskCache(dlw);
   Glide.setup(gb);
}
```

Check [Can't set GlideBuilder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28540216/cant-set-glidebuilder)

Hope its help you.

Comment: setDiskCache is depracated:(